# Inserting PHP database into HTML table

Tags: php, html, database

Hey I've recently been making a website and want to display the data from my database in a grid format opposed to it just listing down the page.

Here is my code right now:

```
<p>
   <a href="pokemondetails.php?dex=<?php echo $row['dex'];?>">
       <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
       <br>
       <img src="assets/<?php echo $row['dex']?>.png">
   </a>
</p>
```

I was wondering how I would go about creating a for loop to allow the data from this database in conjunction with the image to span across the page with 7 columns and however many rows down until it reaches the end of the database.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. It would be good if you actually try to find a solution using different mediums and tutorial sites before posting the question. SO is to find solution to problems you are facing and not to find a solution altogether.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
  $query = "Select * from tablename";
  $bind = $conn->query($query);

  if ($bind->num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $bind->fetch_assoc()){
?>
 <p>
    <a href="pokemondetails.php?dex=<?php echo $row['dex'];?>">
       <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
       <br>
       <img src="assets/<?php echo $row['dex']?>.png">
    </a>
 </p>

<?php
   }
 }
?>
```

Try this, I just add while loop until End Of file (EOF table)